# Regular Equation Numbering in extbook environment without manual \tag?

Tags: equations, books

I am currently using the `extbook` environment and have some chapters and sections. The equations, by default, are being labeled within the chapter that they are in.

Is there any way I can switch the equation labeling to the number of the equation in the entire document (as it typically is, when there are no chapters, sections, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say these lines in your preamble would do the trick:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

I haven't tested yet, though.

Comment: Minus the ] (typo in the second line), it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Corrected the typo, thanks for pointing it!